# Filtering a subclass in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I have a message driven system with, say, com.example.BaseMessagingAgent class, which is a basic class for many message agents. This base class logs message events. There are many subclasses of this base class, implementing different specific agents of system. Let us com.example.MyAgent which extends com.example.BaseMessagingAgent is one of them.

I want to log messages only related to class MyAgent. But I cannot define logging as:

```
log4j.logger.com.example.MyAgent=DEBUG, APPENDER
```

because logging occurs in parent class com.example.BasicMessagingAgent - I will record nothing.

And I also do not want to set logging in base class:

```
log4j.logger.com.example.BaseMessagingAgent=DEBUG, APPENDER
```

because it will log events for all agents, and I will have a lot of unnecessary logging.

Does enyone know how to limit logging to only one subclass?

Comment: How are you defining the Logger in the code?  static?

Comment: This is a third company code. I have only .class files.

Answer (score 1):

You should write a filter for Log4j since AFAIK there is no way to put such information on log4j.properties file. More details at http://books.google.it/books?id=vHvY008Zq-YC&lpg=PA95&ots=yi335bZU7z&dq=&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, actually.

First, add the appender to the root logger. Really. It will make your life much more simple.

Now configure the whole thing:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, APPENDER
log4j.logger.com=ERROR
log4j.logger.com.example.MyAgent=DEBUG
```

The default for all classes below "com.*" will be to log only errors. The sole exception is `com.example.MyAgent` which will log at debug level.

You need to set the root logger to `DEBUG` as well or it will throw away all the DEBUG log messages.

The next step is to use one logger per instance. To get that, simply remove the `static` in the line which you create your logger and replace `BaseMessagingAgent` with `getClass()`

I know, it looks like overkill but that's how log4j works. Also creating a logger per instance isn't very expensive (unless you create millions of `MyAgent` per second).

If you really want to add an appender to a single class, then don't forget to turn off additivity (`...Class.additivity=false`) or you will get all log messages twice.

Comment: I believe the key here is removing the static from the Logger declaration in the code, but @Nulldevice is working with 3rd party code.

Comment: Decompile it; you just need to fix a single line. Just make sure you create a project which even an idiot can build to apply the fix to a new version. If all else fails, filter the "static" flag from the byte code using ASM or a similar tool.